# SQLite select if results in other table are more than n

Tags: sqlite, select, if-statement

I have the following tables in my database:

```
sessions                 measurements
--------                 ------------
id                       id
etc.                     session_id
                         etc.
```

I want to do something like

```
SELECT * FROM sessions IF 
   (measurements HAS MORE THAN 0 RESULTS WHERE session_id=X)
```

Is this sort of query possible in sqlite?

Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Am not sure if SQLite supports EXISTS, so I've provided two alternatives:

```
SELECT *
FROM sessions S
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM measurements WHERE session_is = S.id)
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM sessions S
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM measurements WHERE session_is = S.id) > 0
```

Comment: `EXISTS` is obviously better, and [yes, SQLite supports it](http://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html).

Comment: @9000 - for sure, glad to hear this is supported.

Comment: In the `… EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM …)` form, if `session_id` isn't unique then consider adding `LIMIT 1` to the inner `SELECT`. (I don't know how good the query optimizer is; if it's dumb, the `LIMIT` will greatly reduce the amount of work required to produce results.)

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
select * from sessions where (select count(*) from measurements where session_id=X)>0
```